# importing from file vs internet in genfromtxt numpy date “TypeError: must be str, not bytes” using python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, genfromtxt

Strange enough! but, applying np.genfromtxt() function on the file(goog.csv), wherein the data has been downloaded and stored from a source, produces no error.Following is the code->

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.dates import bytespdate2num

names = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]
my_array1 = np.genfromtxt("goog.csv",                     
                          delimiter=',',
                          skip_header=1,
                          names=names,
                          dtype=None,
                          converters={0: bytespdate2num('%Y-%m-%d')})
print(my_array1["A"])
```

Output->

```
[ 736536.  736535.  736534. ...,  730124.  730123.  730122.]
```

However, applying the same function on a list whose data has been fetched from the same source, being in the same format(.csv), produces the Typerror.Following is the code->

```
import numpy as np
import request
from matplotlib.dates import bytespdate2num

/*fetching the internet data and store it in a list called stock_data*/

source_code = str(requests.get(goog_url, verify=True, auth=('user', 'pass')).content)
stock_data = []
split_source = source_code.split('\\n')
for line in split_source:
    stock_data.append(line)


names = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]
my_array2 = np.genfromtxt(stock_data,
                          delimiter=',',
                          skip_header=1,
                          names=names,
                          dtype=None,
                          converters={0: bytespdate2num('%Y-%m-%d')})
print(my_array2["A"])
```

Output->

```
TypeError: must be str or None, not bytes
```

Data in the link [goog_url](https://pythonprogramming.net/yahoo_finance_replacement) as well as the file (goog.csv) is of the following format->

```
2017-07-26,153.3500,153.9300,153.0600,153.5000,153.5000,12778195.00
```

could find no reason for the difference and error in the second case.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

**Demo:**

```
import numpy as np
import datetime

datefunc = lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x.decode("utf-8"), '%Y-%m-%d')
Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Adjusted_close, Volume = np.genfromtxt(filename, dtype=None, unpack=True, delimiter=',', converters = {0: datefunc}).tolist()
print(Date)
```

**Output:**

```
2017-07-26 00:00:00
```

Comment: It seems this code doesn't apply on python 3.6,still getting the same error:(

Answer (score 0):

Using `decode` like this assumes `x` is bytestring:

```
In [127]: datefunc = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x.decode("utf-8"), '%Y-%m-%d') 
In [128]: datefunc('1999-01-30')
 ....
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
In [129]: datefunc(b'1999-01-30')
```

Without the decode it handles the default PY3 string type:

```
In [130]: datefunc1 = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d') 

In [132]: datefunc1('1999-01-30')
Out[132]: datetime.datetime(1999, 1, 30, 0, 0)
```

Previously `genfromtxt` opened the file in bytestring mode, and thus required this kind of conversion.  But in the current version, it can open the file in unicode, and shouldn't need the `decode`.  If your version of `genfromtxt` accepts an `encoding` parameter (it may be even raise a warning about it), it's new.

Comment: edited it please review